# Simple question about AxesLabel

Tags: plotting

I am plotting a function and for labeling the axes I use:

```
AxesLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 21], Style[{Subscript[f, i], Subscript[q, i]}, FontSize -> 21]}
```

here $y$ is for the $x$-axis and $\{f_i,q_i\}$ is for the $y$-axis. The problem is that I dont want to have $\{\}$. I only want to have $f_i,q_i$ at the $y$-axis. How can I manage this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just use a string for the Y label: `Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(6\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \
\(6\)]\)", FontSize -> 21]` (use ctrl-_ to enter the subscript in the string, then just `Style` the string to desired font size)

Comment: @rasher thanks for a quick reply. It works well, pls put as an answer.

Comment: Glad that helped. Will post as answer as requested, but be advised Q will probably get closed as an "...in the docs..." kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a *string* for the Y-axis label, e.g.:

```
AxesLabel -> 
 {Style[y, FontSize -> 21], 
  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(f\), \(6\)]\),\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(q\), \ \(6\)]\)", 
    FontSize -> 21]}
```

You can use the key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> to enter subscripts directly into the string, then use `Style` on the string to alter font size, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a (mostly) non-string approach, using `Row` to string expressions together:

```
 AxesLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 21], 
               Style[Row[{Subscript[f, i], Subscript[q, i]}, ","], FontSize -> 21]}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringForm.html):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel ->
    (Style[#, 21] & /@ {y, StringForm["`1`,`2`", Subscript[f, 6], Subscript[q, 5]]})]
```

[image]